# Windows Phone 8.1 - File Access From Coded UI Test

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, coded-ui-tests

I'm trying to access the file system for read/write operations on Windows Phone 8.1 from **Coded UI Test** in order to log events and read settings files.

I'm unable to access **Windows.Storage.KnownFolders** due to System.UnauthorizedAccessException and unable to grant permissions due to a lack of an application manifest in a coded UI test.

I'm also unable to access **Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current** because the process has no package identity.

Any ideas on how to solve this?